# duplicate values coming even after adding distinct and group by in php sql function

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, duplicates, datalist

i have a website in php codeigniter, I have a searchbox where users can search and get data from database, the data is displayed using datalist in searhbox, I created the following function for search in codeigniiter:

```html
 public function keywordsearch() {
        
         $this->db->select('category.category_name, link.link_name, group_concat(link.keyword) as keyword');
         $this->db->distinct('link.keyword');
         $this->db->join('category','category.category_name=link.category');
         $this->db->group_by('link.keyword');
         $query = $this->db->get('link');
         return $query->result();
     }
```

my table is below:

[image]

the 4 columns I am using in this function linkname,linkurl,category and keyword. as you can see the table, there are duplicates values in some columns I tried to hide duplicate values using group by and distinct, still i am getting duplicate values like below:

[image]

can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use for group by the same column you want in aggregated  result.
try using the column's name selected  but not aggregated

```
public function keywordsearch() {
    
     $this->db->select('category.category_name, link.link_name
                , group_concat(distinct link.keyword) as keyword');
     $this->db->join('category','category.category_name=link.category');
     $this->db->group_by('category.category_name, link.link_name');
     $query = $this->db->get('link');
     return $query->result();
 }
```

Comment: let me check bro

Comment: check better  ..  and remove distinct clause  .. too .. answer  updated ..

Comment: bro, i want my keyword column to be in group by, coz lot of duplicates values are in keyword column

Comment: your comment have not sense   if you  want avoid duplicated  result  for an aggregated  result  ..  the you must avoid the group by for the column in aggregated ..  if you have duplicated  value in the column you  aggregate then use group_concat(distinct ...) ..  answer updated ..

Comment: bro i tried your code, its still showing duplicates